# I can't import random

Tags: python-2.7, import

I'm new to Python. When I imported `random` and `easygui`, there were these error codes:

> No module named random
>
> No module named easygui

But I have `easygui` installed on my computer.

**Python**

```
import random,easygui
secret=random.randint
```

Comment: random is a builtin module, if you don't have it then you have a broken installation.

Comment: you probably have a file called `random.py` within your project folder that is imported instead of the stdlib module